# How to find the Big-O complexity and worst case running time of this Java program?

Tags: java, big-o

I am having trouble understanding Big-O notation. How do I find the Big-O and worst case running time of this function?

I wrote this function to reverse the order of a doubly linked list.

```
public void reverse() {
    Node<T> temp = head;
    Node<T> current = head.next;
    head.next = null;
    head.previous = current;

    while(current != null)
    {
        Node<T> next = current.next;
        current.next = temp;
        current.previous= next;
        temp = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = tail;
}
```

Comment: Big-O specifies how the running time increases with respect to the input increasing. For example, if your input size increases `k` times, and your running time increases by a polynomial of degree 2, that would be an `O(n^2)` algorithm. For small inputs Big-O is rather useless, as the other factors that affect running time are not negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "data structure" should remind us of a "doubly linked list", and assuming a list of size `n`, this algorithms reverses the order of the list.
We can count now the (compare, assign, mathematical) operations, which this algorithm will accomplish (besides, whether it is correct & terminates) ..in relation to `n`:

And we will find, that this algorithm does (in worst, best & average (so every)) case:

```
4 assign statements:
 Node<T> temp = head;
 Node<T> current = head.next;
 head.next = null;
 head.previous = current;
n + 1 compare statements:
 while(current != null)
(lets not count the braces))
n * 5 assign operations:
 Node<T> next = current.next;
 current.next = temp;
 current.previous= next;
 temp = current;
 current = next;
and 1 last assign operation
 head = tail;
```

so it is `4 + n + 1 + 5 * n + 1 = 6 * n + 6` (assign or compare ... but compare are the "most expensive" ones in terms of run time) operations.
We eliminate constant factors and offset (since they can be neglected, when `n`gets big...and due to exact mathematical rules, we learned), and get:

```
6n + 6 = O(n)
```

..and apropos: it is correct & terminates! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look for the number of nested loops.

Since there isn't one it's just O(n) because there's no geometric reduction of the `n` over the course of the loop